Micronaut: How to intercept the http request and bind the header values to request parameters as Map<String,String> in controller in Micronaut?
I am writing a generic interface for controller which has below signature
interface IUser{
    T createUser(
        Map<String, String> headers,
        String userName
    )
}

This will be implemented by a micronaut project as below
public class UserController implements IUser {
    public HttpResponse createUser(
        **Map<String, String> headers,** // I am looking to get the header value here as similar to @RequestHeader in spring boot
        @PathVariable String userName
    ){

    }
}

I need to know if an Annotation already exists in micronaut to bind the header values or a way to create custom annotation to bind the header values as Map<String, String> as parameter to the controller method.

As you'll see in the docs: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/ , there's no annotation for getting all headers. You can always make your own annotation/binder, have a look at io.micronaut.http.annotation.Header and io.micronaut.http.bind.binders.HeaderAnnotationBinder in https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core

I did some research based on one of the comments and able to get it implemented through custom annotation.
Below are the details
Annotation Creation
import io.micronaut.core.bind.annotation.Bindable;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Bindable
public @interface HeaderMap {}

Annotation Binding
import io.micronaut.core.convert.ArgumentConversionContext;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest;
import io.micronaut.http.bind.binders.AnnotatedRequestArgumentBinder;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Singleton
public class MapHeaderBinder
    implements AnnotatedRequestArgumentBinder<HeaderMap, Map<String, String>> {

  @Override
  public Class<HeaderMap> getAnnotationType() {
    return HeaderMap.class;
  }

  @Override
  public BindingResult<Map<String, String>> bind(
      ArgumentConversionContext<Map<String, String>> argument, HttpRequest<?> source) {
    Map<String, String> headersMap =
        source.getHeaders().asMap().entrySet().stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> String.join(",", entry.getValue())));

    return () -> Optional.of(headersMap);
  }
}

Usage in Controller
public class UserController implements IUser {
    public HttpResponse<?> createUser(
        @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
        @PathVariable String userName
    ){
        // Controller Implementation
    }
}

